# Meteor 1.2.1 version Meteor.method({}) inside server code does not work

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

Client-side click `sendlogmessage` calls the event, but the method inside the server-side program does not call `sendlogmessage`.

`console.log` didn't work. Can anyone help me finding the answer?

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.mytemplate.events({
        "click": function () {
            Meteor.call('sendLogMessage');
        }
    })
}    

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'sendLogMessage': function(){
            console.log("Hello world");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify a selector for the event. Are you sure that the client actually calls the server method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is working. You just have to specify the element you are clicking on that should trigger the event. Something like this:

```
HTML
<template name="mytemplate">
    <p id="clicable">Click me!</p>
</template>

JAVASCRIPT
Template.mytemplate.events({
    "click #clicable": function() {
        Meteor.call('sendLogMessage');
    }
})
```

or

```
HTML
<template name="mytemplate">
    <p class="clicable">Click me!</p>
</template>

JAVASCRIPT
Template.mytemplate.events({
    "click .clicable": function() {
        Meteor.call('sendLogMessage');
    }
})
```